# UFW logs showing suspicious activity

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I am using UFW and have some rules in action.
My current status for the firewall is as the image below.

[image: ufw]

However, I noticed in the log files located at `/var/log/ufw.log` that there are many incoming requests from IPs that I am not aware. And given the fact that this is a test server recently built, I suspect I am under attack as all the destination requests are heading to a certain IP address. Below is a sample of the log file.

```
Mar 5   6:25:35 backend1    kernel: SRC=14.184.171.85   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:25:48 backend1    kernel: SRC=179.27.81.68    DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:25:51 backend1    kernel: SRC=104.255.70.247  DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:26:10 backend1    kernel: SRC=82.162.189.53   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:27:01 backend1    kernel: SRC=111.78.66.156   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:27:46 backend1    kernel: SRC=196.52.43.51    DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:29:27 backend1    kernel: SRC=24.41.189.148   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:30:36 backend1    kernel: SRC=24.41.211.202   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:33:22 backend1    kernel: SRC=80.82.70.26     DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:34:42 backend1    kernel: SRC=178.245.183.28  DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:38:26 backend1    kernel: SRC=221.194.44.229  DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:38:44 backend1    kernel: SRC=80.201.117.228  DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:39:40 backend1    kernel: SRC=177.135.11.3    DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:40:06 backend1    kernel: SRC=183.217.28.46   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:40:48 backend1    kernel: SRC=110.77.72.212   DST=138.68.78.215
Mar 5   6:41:26 backend1    kernel: SRC=195.154.237.46  DST=138.68.78.215
```

Is this normal?

Comment: This is what that IP belongs to https://db-ip.com/138.68.78.215 it is not normal, if you have no association with Digital Ocean, block it

Comment: @MarkKirby, I have association with the address, but I am worried about the huge number of requests coming from unknown addresses.

Comment: In that case, it may be better to ask them directly here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions

Comment: What you are observing is normal. Any externally facing device will always be probed by a variety of bad people wanting to do bad stuff.

Comment: You could utilise tcpdump to at least get a better picture on the activity  `sudo tcpdump -i <interface>  -X > /root/log.txt` should do the trick. For more....man tcpdump. Might also be a good idea to install both network based and host based IDS.

Comment: restrict the addresses which can access the server through ufw. Got no tidings to china or russia, find those IP blocks and put them on your list. Thids will reduce chatter and makes it harder for script bots from "bad sources" to probe you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal.

It is the background noise of being connected to the internet. There's bots that scan for vulnerabilities, probe passwords of ssh-servers, and there's network scanners continuously mapping the internet. There's researchers gathering data, and there's [search engines](https://shodan.io) mapping open ports on internet connected machines.

Either ignore it, or if it bothers you, set up a tool like `fail2ban` to drop brute force attempts.